# Frontpage caching logged out

Tags: users, caching

I have stumbled upon a caching problem. The scenario is the following.
I log in as admin. I visit another node. I return to the frontpage. 
Result is that the frontpage is showing as if I am not logged in.

I think it is a caching issue, since checking from Network I can see that the frontpage is cached.

There is a problem that this is caused by modification of the html.tpl.php file.
I have added.

```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Sun, 01 Jan 2012 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Do you have any ideas or dealt with a similar issue?

Comment: Is your site behind Varnish (or another reverse proxy)?

Comment: No it is not behind varnish.

Comment: Can you reproduce this is any combination of machine/browser? (i.e., have you determined it's not a problem with over-aggressive browser caching?)

Comment: No I have not determined it. When no browser caching is  there it can not be reproduced. I can reproduce it in 3 different machines google-chrome/safari.